# Пунктуация в сложноподчиненном предложении

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп

Нужна ли запятая перед союзом "и"?

**Это организация, которая находится в городе Магнитогорск (Россия) и к которой относятся: ...**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Это организация, которая находится в городе Магнитогорск (Россия) и к*
>   *которой относятся...*
>
> Нужна ли запятая перед союзом "и"?

[**Не нужна. См.:**](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=134#pp134)

> **§ 119.** В сложноподчиненных предложениях с несколькими однородными придаточными знаки препинания ставятся по правилам, действующим при
>   отделении однородных членов простого предложения...
>
> <…>
>
> 2. Между двумя придаточными, соединенными одиночными соединительными или разделительными союзами ***и, или, либо, да*** (в значении «и»),
>      запятая не ставится (при этом подчинительный союз или союзное слово
>      может и не повторяться): *Подходя к дому, я вспомнил, что неподалеку в
>      еловом перелеске с можжевельником не раз спугивал старого
>      петуха-черныша и еще там жила матка с одним молодым петушком*...